# Proving that an entire, bounded function is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove the following :
Let f be entire and assume that $$|f(z)| \leq M|z|^n$$ for large z, for a constant M, and for some integer. Show that f is a polynomial of degree $\leq$ n

Here are my thoughts on the problem so far:
Since we have the inequality above we know that f must be bounded by $M|z*|^n$ where z* = argmax(f) and n large enough to satisfy the inequality. Given that f is bounded and entire I think I can use Liouville's theorem which says that f should be constant. I am currently not sure how to go from f being constant to f being a polynomial, however.

Comment: Note that your reasoning cannot be correct: $f(z) = z^n$ satisfies the given inequality, but is not constant.

Comment: This is a moot point, following Martin R's comment, but: constants are polynomials.  ($c = c + 0z + 0z^2$, for example, if that helps.)

Comment: Use Cauchy estimate